# Serilialize Form Control

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a TypeScript class with these properties:

```
  date_from_control       : FormControl = new FormControl();
  date_to_control         : FormControl = new FormControl();
  date_from               : Date;
  date_to                 : Date;
```

I use FormControl for a DatePicker Field Form pared with Class.

```
<mat-form-field  appearance="outline">
  <input matInput
         [matDatepicker]='picker_from_i'
         [formControl]="item.date_from_control"
  >
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker_from_i"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #picker_from_i></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Unfortunally, when I try to send this object with an api, I get an error about serializing:

```
Converting circular structure to JSON --> starting at object with constructor 'SafeSubscriber' | property '_finalizers' -> object with con
```

If I set null to these two FormControl properties before calling the service, it works fine but I cant do it because I lost the field compiled value and in case of server error, the form will be blanked with the risk to submit a null date pressing save another time.

Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can **not** send a FormControl to an API

I imagine you want simply

```
sendData(data:MyClass)
{
   //see how you create an object "ad hoc" using the value of your "data"
   this.myService.sendData({
        date_from:data.date_from
        date_to:data.date_from
   })
}
```

But, really, really it's a very strange your class. I don't know about your requirements, but I imagine you can re-think your application.

Comment: I hope I don't have to create a "sendable" version of my class just to remove two FormControl...

Comment: @EviSvil, Try make a copy of your Class -if is a simple object you can use the spread operator: `const data={...myClassObject}` before remove the properties